# Blur part of screen for Tutorial

Tags: css, ember.js

I'd like to create a nice user experience, when my users login on my dashboard for the first time.
Basically, I'd like to walk them through the different features by focusing on one feature (one part of the screen) at a time, and show a quick tooltip to give a little bit of text.

If anyone has in mind the tutorial for hotjar...

Would anyone know how to call this feature/design?
Do you know of any frameworks which does this in emberJS? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034485/ios-7s-blurred-overlay-effect-using-css

CSS3 only though.

Comment: http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/

Comment: This is another plugin to achieve this effect: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Flexible-Interactive-jQuery-Page-Walkthrough-Plugin/demo/